# Checksum = "SHA-256" not working

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am trying to deploy an application using Powershell DSC; it mostly works, except that I also want the executables to be checked everytime, using a checksum :

```
Checksum = "SHA-256"
```

It simply does not work, DSC doesn't see that the executable must be replace by a newer version; same thing with SHA-1. However, this works :

```
Checksum = "modifiedDate"
```

But I don't want to rely on a date, I really want the contents of the executable to be 100% correct.

Any idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Post the entire configuration (or at least the `File` resource definition). Did you set `MatchSource = $true`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to briantist for pointing to what was missing :

```
MatchSource = $true
```

It is very surprising to me that the default of "MatchSource" is $false...